# Is it ok to check if params exists to evaluate outcome

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

Is it ok to check if params exists to decide which partial to render?

I have a search input which returns the results to an index action, if the user has just visited the index action i would like to return a 'index_partail' but if the user has searched something I would like to return a 'search_partial', something like:

```
unless params[:search].empty?
  render 'post_head'
else
  render 'search_head'  
end
```

Is there any problems doing it this way or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Searching is a very different operation than just showing a page--wouldn't you also need to do a lookup if the search parameter is present? To me, it sounds like different operations, hence different actions.

That said, there are worse things. I'd consider reversing the condition, though.

```
if params[:search].empty? ...etc...
```

I don't find this usage of `unless` to be very readable, but that's mostly preference.

Comment: I originally had a search controller and view, but the search is only to find posts, and the index action of the post controller lists posts in exactly the same way as the search results, so I eventually moved the search results to the posts index view and decided to change the head of the page from a 'Listing Posts' heading to a '12 results' heading, through partials.

Comment: @Darcbar88 Yeah, I understand. I'd consider adding a REST action for search, or using two methods, or something--depends on other stuff not included in the post, though. As long as it works, is clear and concise, it often boils down to your own style.